# async Future is not working in my code. How to fix it?

Tags: firebase, flutter, geofirestore

This function always returning null but it is loading data but it is not waiting for Firestore reading. How to solve this issue?

```
 Future<HomePage> read({ String pageName,String mAppId})async{

  await Firestore.instance
       .collection('tablePages')
       .where('projectId', isEqualTo: mAppId)
       .where("page.title", isEqualTo:pageName)
       .snapshots()
       .listen((data) async{
     if (data.documents != null
         ? data.documents.length > 0
         ? data.documents[0].data != null
         : false
         : false) {


        return HomePage.fromJson(
            data.documents[0].data['page']);
     } else {

       return null;
     }

     //break;
   }).onError((error){

    print(error);
     return null;
   });

  }
}
```

Comment: i think firebase snapshot is stream, so you can't await.

Comment: Viren is correct. If you want to wait for the data, use `get()`.

Comment: @Midhilaj have you tried my answer?

Comment: No, due to delay, I user another logic to solve this issue. I will try your answer and accept it if it is working fine later

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
  Future<HomePage> read({String pageName, String mAppId}) async {
    Stream<QuerySnapshot> snap = Firestore.instance
        .collection('tablePages')
        .where('projectId', isEqualTo: mAppId)
        .where("page.title", isEqualTo: pageName)
        .snapshots();
    await for (var data in snap) {
      if (data.documents != null
          ? data.documents.length > 0 ? data.documents[0].data != null : false
          : false) {
        return HomePage.fromJson(data.documents[0].data['page']);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    }
  }
```

From the docs:

> Streams can be created in many ways, which is a topic for another article, but they can all be used in the same way: the asynchronous for loop (commonly just called await for) iterates over the events of a stream like the for loop iterates over an Iterable. For example:

```
Future<int> sumStream(Stream<int> stream) async {
  var sum = 0;
  await for (var value in stream) {
    sum += value;
  }
  return sum;
}
```

> This code simply receives each event of a stream of integer events, adds them up, and returns (a future of) the sum. When the loop body ends, the function is paused until the next event arrives or the stream is done.

https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams